# How to make dynamic numberOfPages with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

i'm using bootstrap 3 to make pagination list like that:

```
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li id="editable_previous" class="js_paginate_button_previous previous disabled"><a href="#">Précédent</a></li>
        <li class="js_paginate_button active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li class="js_paginate_button "><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li class="js_paginate_button "><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li class="js_paginate_button "><a href="#">4</a></li>
        <li class="js_paginate_button "><a href="#">5</a></li>
        <li id="editable_next" class="js_paginate_button_next next"><a href="#">Suivant</a></li>
    </ul>
```

As you could see the number of pages displayed is static (5 pages). I need to make it dynamic. I mean i get the number of pages dynamically from the backend depending on the elements stored in the database.
I can return the number of pages from the backend like this:

```
Entities.MyModelCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url : "../services/api/models",
        model : Entities.MyModel,
        parse : function(data) {
            console.log("number of pages  : "+data.nbrPages);
            return data.list;
        }
    });
```

But how can i display `data.nbrPages` in my `<ul/>` composant? and make 5 pages visible each click on the next button.

Comment: Do you need google like pagination?

Comment: Yes i need to make pagination like google but with bootstrap and jquery